# Browser session never created when video recoding is enabled

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, selenoid

I have a problem that all my browser sessions are "pending" when video recording enabled. After a while i just getting timeout exceptions.

/status

```
{
    "total": 11,
    "used": 0,
    "queued": 0,
    "pending": 2,
    "browsers": {
        "chrome": {
            "65.0": {}
        }
    }
}
```

browsers.json:

```
{
  "chrome": {
    "default": "65.0",
    "versions": {
      "65.0": {
        "image": "selenoid/vnc:chrome_65.0",
        "port": "4444",
        "path": "/"
      }
    }
  }
```

Selenoid container logs:
https://gist.github.com/Xotabu4/02f04e006e0328fe3d229e7b961bb743#file-selenoid_containe-log

Video recorder log:
https://gist.github.com/Xotabu4/02f04e006e0328fe3d229e7b961bb743#file-video_recorder_container-log

selenoid container start config (chef cookbook):
https://gist.github.com/Xotabu4/02f04e006e0328fe3d229e7b961bb743#file-selenoid-rb

Comment: Please check that network communication between containers is not blocked by firewalls in your operating system. CentOS and friends are known to suffer from this. Also please check that you system metrics are OK.

Comment: @vania-pooh maybe some advices about how to check communication between containers? Some scripts, monitoring advices...

Comment: E.g. https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-temporarily-permanently-in-centos-rhel-fedora/